# iOS Safari: 100% width fixed position header wider than viewport

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have run in to a problem that effects specifically Safari on iOS.

I am building a page which has a fixed position header that is the width of the viewport. The content of the page is a series of images (variable in number) which should scroll to the right. The header should remain in place when the user scrolls.

On iOS Safari, the fixed header, is slightly larger than the viewport, and also scrolls at a different speed than the rest of the content.

I've cut the code down to the following, and still cannot work out how to solve this problem - the following code works perfectly in all other browsers that I have tested. (I am targeting IE8+)

I've hosted the example of this problem [here.](http://peterbarwick.co.uk/iostest)

Thanks for any advice and help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style>
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    height:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#dgs2 {
    height:75%;
    display:inline-block;
}
img{
    height: 100%;
}
#pad{
    height:6em;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
#header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:6em;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
.menuRight{
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="menuRight"><h2>Menu</h2></div>
        <h1>Testing scroll on iPhone</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pad"></div>
    <div id="dgs2">
        <img src='img/red.png'/><img src='img/blue.png'/><img src='img/red.png'/><img src='img/blue.png'/><img src='img/red.png'/><img src='img/blue.png'/><img src='img/red.png'/><img src='img/blue.png'/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this question is a year old at this point, but the issue still exists in iOS and I had the EXACT same issue with fixed elements drifting, and it was driving me nuts. The answer is pretty simple: Just wrap the div #bgs2 (or whatever element has "white-space:nowrap" on it) with div.wrapper (the class is unimportant obviously), and set the overflow to auto:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I also added webkit-overflow-scrolling, which helps with avoiding repaints.

Someone in the future is bound to find this bizarre issue, so hopefully it helps.

Comment: You're right, if I recall correctly I did end up doing something like that, was a nightmare and I could never work out exactly what I did to fix it. Thanks for answering for all the other lost souls in this iOS wasteland

Answer (score 0):

If your happy using jQuery, then you could use something like:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
  $("#header").width(bodyWidth).css('width', bodyWidth);
});
```

I included both the attribute width and the css width, just to be sure it works in all browsers. Also if you change your meta tag to:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

That should also help.

Update 1

Sorry, I didn't read the CSS styles properly for the header. The styles for the header should be as follows:

```
#header{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0; // Set these positioning attributes 
    left: 0; // to hold the header in the top left.
    width:100%;
    height:6em;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

Update 2

Again, another CSS update. I notice you have code like follows:

```
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    height:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#dgs2 {
    height:75%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You need to change it to read like the following:

```
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#dgs2 {
    height:75%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you move the `white-space: nowrap;` to the `#dsg2` div instead of assigning it to the `html` then this should be your final fix. Also, add the following to the jQuery code to accompany what you have already:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
  $("#header").width(bodyWidth).css('width', bodyWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this does improve things by forcing the header to the correct size, but if I scroll horizontally the header still moves with the page, and strangely, at a slower rate. It needs to stay fixed in place, as it does on other browsers.

Comment: Just updated my answer with some CSS styles. This should 100% fix your problem, I had a similar problem but with a sidebar that was scrolling vertically as I missed these attributes.

Comment: Thanks again, I agree that should work but unfortunately the header is still scrolling with the page (slower than the images) on Safari on iOS devices.

Comment: Looks ok to me, tested on iPhone 5S, 6, iPad mini 3 and an iPad Air

Comment: Plus an iPhone 4S and an iPod.

Comment: Testing on (simulated) iPad Air (8.0), iPad Mini (8.0), iPad 4th (7.0), iPhone 5S (7.0) all now works correctly.
When I test on a (real) iPhone 5c with iOS8.2 the header still has buggy behaviour, as well as (simulated) iPhone 6+ (8.0), iPhone 6 (8.0).
I've added an updated test incorporating your suggestions [here](http://peterbarwick.co.uk/iostest/test2.php). Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Test the above update and it should be sorted. The `white-space: nowrap;` is what is making your header scroll and the extra jQuery will make the header correct when the window resizes, helps if someone views the site on a mobile device and changes the device orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on device orientation. I just [tried moving the css into the dgs2 block](http://peterbarwick.co.uk/iostest/test2.php) and there unfortunately was no change to the behaviour on the iPhone 5c (untested on others).  If I try with a fixed width block which does not have any images, and without `whitespace:no-wrap`, then the header movement works as intended. The problems does seem to stem from the use of `whitespace:no-wrap` to force a horizontal scroll on the images.