# 100% width in mobile devices is more than viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem making the design for the mobile version of a website. I have this modal and I want to make it stretch for the entire width of the screen, so I added the following css:

```
.suggestions-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: white;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

The structure of the html is the following:

```
<body>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div ng-view class='ng-scope'>
            <div id="full-warning" class="visible-xs visible-sm md-modal full-color warning md-effect-8 suggestions-modal fadeIn" ng-show="showModal">
```

If I inspect every element I can see the following dimensions:

```
 <body> <!-- 320 x 568 -->
        <div class='container-fluid'> <!-- 320 x 6835 -->
            <div ng-view class='ng-scope'> <!-- 290 x 6835 -->
                <div id="full-warning" class="visible-xs visible-sm md-modal full-color warning md-effect-8 suggestions-modal fadeIn" ng-show="showModal"> <!-- 360 x 639 -->
```

I can't understand why by putting the width to 100% it goes above the width of the device.
(in this case an iphone 5, with 320px of total width)

I have this metatag in the html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There is nothing inside the modal with a fixed width, if I empty and leave just the modal div, with nothing else inside, it still have the same dimensions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that we can see the problem?

Comment: check that you don't have content inside that div with a fixed width of 300+ px

Comment: This looks like your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315889/ios-safari-100-width-fixed-position-header-wider-than-viewport